# XCode, Appium: Can we run our iOS tests in the native simulator in MacOS with M1 chip?

Tags: xcode, macos, intel, apple-m1, appium-ios

Just a question. There has been a discussion in our organization that we cannot build our iOS app in a Mac with M1 Pro chip :/ I don't believe it honestly and I think it's possible. But is it possible? We've also been encountering different errors in MacOS like some imports are not available in M1 Pro but are available in Intel chip. I tried to search for related topics but can't find much information if the user in the tutorials are using Intel chip or M1 Pro chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appium supports M1 chips since version 1.20.0 which was released almost 2 years ago and I doubt it matters if it is a Pro chip or not. To be sure you should use Appium 2.x with the latest `xcuitest` driver installed (Appium 1.x is not actively maintained anymore). If you cannot build your own app on M1 Pro chip - that issue is not related to Appium.